# Flutter: ElevatedButton has different theme on Linux

Tags: flutter, button, themes

### Problem

I have a Flutter application that uses an [**ElevatedButton**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) widget.
When I run the application on Windows the button colors are fine, but when I run it on Linux, they are different.

Here's my code :

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
        // ...
    },
    child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 60,
        child: const Text(
            "Avvia",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

### Result

On Windows:

[image]

On Linux (Kali Linux on WSL):

[image]

---

Does anybody know *why* it happens and *how* can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find any reference, but the problem is appearently linked to the **Flutter SDK version** I was using: on WSL Kali Linux I had a more recent Flutter version, while on Windows an older one.

When I **upgraded flutter** on Windows, to version `3.16.0` the theme of ElevatedButton changed, matching the one I had on Linux:

[image]